# Silverlight datagrid styling MVVM

Tags: silverlight, styling

I am having some trouble styling the `Silverlight` `DataGrid`, I do have experience with `WPF` styles and have styled my `DataGrid` in WPF to my satisfaction, but now i am trying to style my `Silverlight` `DataGrid` the same as my `WPF`, but it seems `Silverlight styles` do not have `Style.Triggers`. How can I convert my `WPF DataGrid` to `Silverlight`?

Style below:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid" x:Key="DataGridStyle">

    <!-- Make the border and grid lines a little less imposing -->
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DDDDDD" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="#DDDDDD" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="#DDDDDD" />
    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>

    <Setter Property="RowStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!-- Highlight a grid row as the mouse passes over -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>

            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="CellStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!-- Highlight selected rows -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF41B1E1" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF41B1E1" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>

                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewTextInput" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewTextInput" />

                <!-- Add some padding around the contents of a cell -->
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,3,4,3" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have noted that `Silverlight` uses `VisualStateManager` but can't seem to get mine up and running using it.

My only 2 real concerns are that I want to change the Text Color (`Foreground`) to black as it is not visible currently as my `Background` is white, and then changing the color (`Background`) of the selected cell.

Thank you

Comment: Best place to start in my opinion, is using Blend, pull out the [default control templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066(v=vs.95).aspx) (or look in the default resource dictionary holding those templates which I think is named SdkStyles.xaml) and instead of trying to write it from scratch, just edit a default template copy to your requirement. You'll probably find it less painful than you might expect pretty quick.

Comment: @ChrisW., I went for more or less the same approach, we used to use styles from the `Silverlight Toolkit`, although they are not very pretty they worked. Now that we are moving to our own styles I downloaded the source from the `Silverlight Toolkit` and I am disecting the parts that we need. The one problem is that even with their styles, they do not change the foreground color, which is leading me to believe it is impossible - which would be very strange.

Comment: Never say never, you could always embed your `ContentPresenter` in something like a `UserControl` and apply it to that. So something literally like `<UserControl Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"><ContentPresenter/></UserControl>` would work also.